# Java Create Vector of Vector with given size

Tags: java, vector, 2d

I am having trouble converting a simple line of C++ Code to Java. I want to declare a 2D Vector with a given size. In C++ I just use this line of code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyObject>> treeVector(xSize, std::vector<MyObject>(ySize));
```

Pretty easy. Doing so my Vector get's created with an empty object inside each cell using the default constructor of the class. This makes it easy to work on with it.

I am googling and searching stackoverflow for an hour now but I can't come up with something. Best I can do is creating an completly empty 2D Vector. Is Java not capable of doing like C++ does? Do I need to create the vector empty and go through a nested for loop to bring it to the size desired?

Comment: Does it have to be `Vector`? Would you not use a `List` of some sort instead? Neither have a fixed size in java, so they grow as needed.

Comment: Or if it must be of a defined size, then an array perhaps?

Comment: I think you want use `arraylist` which is equivalent  for c++ vector

Comment: Isn't a array old and not flexible at all? What is the difference between a list and a Vector then?

Comment: Vector is synchronized

Comment: As far as I read you have to loop through your ArrayList as well to create the contents. So then I can also use the doubled Vector ..? Don't know what synchronized means tbh ..

Comment: @Leo.1906: I don't think "old" is a concern. It's an original part of the language and thus a foundational concept. It is "inflexible" in that it has a defined size that cannot change, but it *almost* looks like that was what you're looking for.

Comment: On further reading, my guess is that you want to use a List, and use streams to create it.

Comment: Ok I will concider using an Array. I learned to never use Arrays unless you are on basic C language. In C++ always use Vector because they are as fast as Arrays and you wont mess up so fast

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can you help me out with the code on this one?

Comment: Also what do you call an *empty object*, do you mean `null`? Or instances with no set state

Comment: @Lino In C++ it would be whatever the default no-arg constructor would give you, so, `0` for `int` (yes, a primitive has a ctor in C++), or whatever the `MyObject()` ctor gives you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `List` of `Lists` of `MyObject`, you could do it like this with Java streams:

```
public class MyObject {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject";
    }
}

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TwoD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int xSize = 7;
        int ySize = 11;
        List<List<MyObject>> treeVector = Stream.generate(
                () -> Stream.generate(MyObject::new).limit(ySize).collect(toList()))
            .limit(xSize).collect(toList());
        System.out.println(treeVector);
    }
}
```

The inner `Stream.generate` creates a list of new `MyObjects` (potentially infinite), limits it to size `ySize`, and collects it into a Java `List`. The outer `Stream.generate` is similar, but instead of a `List` of `MyObjects`, it's creating a list of those lists (`xSize` of them, specifically).

I should add, the `() -> ...` syntax is a lambda that will be used to generate each of the lists, and the `MyObject::new` is a method reference to the `MyObject` ctor, which is used rather like a lambda, to create the `MyObjects`.

(Note: "rather like a lambda" isn't strictly technically accurate, but this is just to quickly explain to someone coming from a C++ background.)